# terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistency:

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    DataCell1 *cell1=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    DataCell2 *cell2=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    DataCell3 *cell3=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   // UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#> forIndexPath:<#(NSIndexPath *)#>]
    switch (indexPath.section) {
            NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.section);
        case 0:
            if(cell1!=nil)
                cell1.lblShowCell1.text=@"abc";

            return cell1;
            break;
        case 1:

            if(cell2!=nil)
                cell2.lblShow2.text=@"def";

            return cell2;
            break;
        case 2:
            if(cell3!=nil)

                cell3.lblShow3.text=@"xyz";

        default:
            break;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

Comment: Returning nil? Log all the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DataCell1 *cell1=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    DataCell2 *cell2=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    DataCell3 *cell3=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in above lines you are trying to dequeue all the cells with single indexpath. You should check your indexpath and dequeue the cell accordingly.

for eg:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
     DataCell1 *cell1=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else if(indexPath.row == 1){
     DataCell1 *cell1=[self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

And also **you are returning nil. you return Cell**